# What approach does asp.net mvc supports?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Hai guys,

I know asp.net web forms supports event driven programming approach and it has 'n' number of events.
Now my question is

- What approach does asp.net mvc supports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ASP.NET MVC supports the HTTP approach**. No, really. While you can develop WebForms applications without really knowing about HTTP (I've seen this a lot), with ASP.NET MVC you need to know at least the basics about HTTP.

This sounds as if ASP.NET MVC was some kind of low-level framework, but it's not. You get a lot of help from the framework, but at the same you don't have to sacrifice the flexibility that the web technologies (HTTP / HTML / CSS / JS) provide.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are no UI applications which work without events.

ASP.NET MVC is also event driven here you would mostly be using JQuery.